# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when using Range.Offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when Selecting Range using Range.Offset. A lot of my codes contain `If` and `ElseIf` and I only changed the values, did not even touch the codes. The VBA worked just fine before I changed the values in `IF` statements. Now it keeps giving me Runtime Error.

Here are my codes. They are very long, though.

```
Sub compare2()

Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16



Do While A <= 42
    i = 2
    Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

        If Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

         ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Podding" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = " " And Cells(i, B) = " " Then
        Cells(i, c) = " "

        Else


        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop



    A = A + 4
    B = A + 1
    c = A + 2
Loop


End Sub
```

The second one:

```
Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)


    Dim sales_cell As Range
    Dim production_cell As Range
    Dim day_cell As Range

    If changed_cell.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Set sales_cell = changed_cell
        Set production_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, 1)
        Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        Set production_cell = changed_cell
        Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)
        Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)
    End If


    On Error GoTo multiple_changes

    If sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Green"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Green"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
       day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
       day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
       day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Rollup"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Green"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Available"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Available"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Available"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Available"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Outside"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Outside"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Outside"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Outside"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Podding" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Rollup"



        ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Red" Then
       day_cell = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"



        ElseIf sales_cell = " " And production_cell = " " Then
        day_cell = " "


        Else

        End If

        Exit Sub

multiple_changes:

Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16



Do While A <= 42
    i = 2
    Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

        If Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Yellow" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Red" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Available"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Available" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



         ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Outside" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Outside"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Podding" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Title Transfer"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Title Transfer" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"



        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = " " And Cells(i, B) = " " Then
        Cells(i, c) = " "

        Else


        End If
        i = i + 1

        Loop



    A = A + 4
    B = A + 1
    c = A + 2

    Loop

End Sub
```

I'm not sure why my former colleagues repeat those `If` and `ElseIf` conditions many times. Please advise me howI can improve these codes.

Also, when I clicked debug, the `Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)` in the 2nd batch kept being highlighted.

Some extra info, my sales_cell is the 14th column (column N), production_cell is the 15th column (column O).

This is what I have in the sheet that is supposed to use Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call Module1.single_change(Target)

End Sub
```

Here is how the Macro should work (but it doesn't though). 
I have a set of 4 adjacent columns: Column N (or Sales), Column O (or Production), Column P (known as Day#), and Column Q (known as Status). the way it works is whatever the user puts/changes in Column N (Sales) and Column M (Production), the macro will return the corresponding value from the `If` statements. And that applies the same way to the next 4 columns and so on.

Any help is very much appreciated. I've stuck with this problem for days and still have no idea what the issue really is.

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely `changed_cell` is in column A and you can't offset one column to the left.

Comment: Open the code in VBE and press F8. Keep pressing until you get an error, then edit your question and add information about the line that generates an error.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak - `Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)` is the offending line.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, ```Set production_cell = changed_cell``` then ```Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)```. And my production_cell is supposed to be column O and sales_cell is column N. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Test is the column is `1` before attempting to offset.

Comment: Hi @AlisonCleverly! Can we see the code that calls "single_change"? Maybe there is something going on with the range that it is passing in. I can't see it anywhere in "compare2"

Comment: hi @hammythepig , unfortunately everything I posted above is what I have in my Module. tThe original file works just fine but this one keeps giving me error.

Comment: Thanks for adding that Alison :) so it looks like your code runs whenever a cell is changed, are you changing anything in Column A, that would make this error occur? Or does it occur when you change something in column O like you mentioned?
@neophlegm thanks, OP just added that as I asked!

Comment: Could you add some debug print-outs to see what the variables are set to at the point it crashes? For instance just above the offending line put in something like `Debug.Print changed_cell.address` to print out what cell you're changing that's causing problems?

Comment: @hammythepig sorry I'm not very familiar with VBA but my columns where the Macro should work are supposed to start from column N onwards. And values in columns Sales and Production can be changed any time. It's really weird, when I pasted my data from column A to column M, it always gives me the Runtime Error. I couldn't even change the values in those Sales and Production columns

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you call it whenever ANY cell is changed in your workbook.
Then it tries to run the code on that changed cell and the cells beside it.
This means if you change something in Column B, Column B, C, and D would be affected.

If we update it to only change if you change column N/R/V or O/S/W, or any repeated columns after that, then you should no longer receive the error.

Try updating all of "single_change" to:

```
Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)

Dim sales_cell As Range
Dim production_cell As Range
Dim day_cell As Range
Dim col_num as Integer

col_num = changed_cell.Column
If changed_cell.Column < 14 then 'Dont do anything before Col N
    Exit Sub
Else
    col_num = changed_cell.Column - 14
End if

If col_num  Mod 4 = 0 Then
    Set sales_cell = changed_cell
    Set production_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, 1)
    Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 2)
ElseIf (col_num - 1)  Mod 4 = 0 Then
    Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)
    Set production_cell = changed_cell
    Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)
Else
    'Dont do anything between Col N,O and their repeated values
    Exit Sub
End If

If sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Green"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Green"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
   day_cell = "Yellow"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
   day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Yellow"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Yellow"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
    day_cell = "Yellow"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Yellow" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
    day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
   day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Red" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
    day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Rollup"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Green"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
    day_cell = "Yellow"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Red"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
    day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Available"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Available"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
    day_cell = "Available"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Available"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Available" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
    day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Outside"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Outside"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
    day_cell = "Outside"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Outside" And production_cell = "Red" Then
    day_cell = "Outside"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Podding" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Rollup"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
    day_cell = "Title Transfer"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Green" Then
    day_cell = "Title Transfer"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
    day_cell = "Title Transfer"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Red" Then
   day_cell = "Title Transfer"
ElseIf sales_cell = "Title Transfer" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
    day_cell = "Overdue"
ElseIf sales_cell = " " And production_cell = " " Then
    day_cell = " "
Else
    'Do nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi @hammythepig , I adjusted the codes and no longer have the Run-time error but another issue arises. I tested by entering values on N2 (Sales) and O2 (Production), cell P2 returned correctly what I wanted. However, when I moved on to the next row, I got an error saying "No registered JIT debugger was specified". Then the whole file crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a question, my Sales column would occur every 4 columns from column N. So column M is my 1st Sales column, then column R would be my next Sales column and so on. Same for Production, 1st is column O, 2nd is column S and so on. Would the ```If changed_cell.Column = 14 Then``` and ```ElseIf changed_cell.Column = 15 Then``` be the problem? Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks for the info @AlisonCleverly! I've never heard of "No registered JIT debugger was specified", but going off your second comment, I updated the code, let me know if that works :)

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help so far. I only adjusted the ```Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 2)``` to ```Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)``` and no longer have the Runtime error. However, it seems my Sales and Production cells do not return the correct results even though the If statements were all correct. For example, when I entered Rollup in cell N2 (Sales) then Green in O2 (Production), pressed Enter then all 3 cells Sales, Production, and Day automatically had Green as their values. The Sales cell surprisingly changed on its own accord. Any ideas?