# VBA If-ElseIf statements do not return correct results

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with my If-ElseIf statements since the cell values did not return correct results.

Below are the codes in my Module:

1st batch:

```
Sub compare2()
Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16

Do While A <= 42
i = 2
Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

If Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Green"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Green"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Red"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = " " And Cells(i, B) = " " Then
Cells(i, c) = " "

Else

End If

i = i + 1

Loop


A = A + 4

B = A + 1

c = A + 2

Loop


End Sub
```

2nd batch in Module:

```
Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)

    Dim sales_cell As Range
    Dim production_cell As Range
    Dim day_cell As Range
    Dim col_num As Integer

col_num = changed_cell.Column
If changed_cell.Column < 14 Then 'Dont do anything before Col N
Exit Sub
Else
col_num = changed_cell.Column - 14
End If

If col_num Mod 4 = 0 Then

Set sales_cell = changed_cell
Set production_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, 1)
Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)

ElseIf (col_num - 1) Mod 4 = 0 Then

Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)
Set production_cell = changed_cell
Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, -1)

Else

'Dont do anything between Col N,O and their repeated values

Exit Sub

End If

On Error GoTo multiple_changes

If sales_cell = "Green" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
day_cell = "Green"

ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
day_cell = "Rollup"

ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Green" Then
day_cell = "Green"

ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
day_cell = "Yellow"

ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Red" Then
day_cell = "Red"

ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
day_cell = "Overdue"

ElseIf sales_cell = " " And production_cell = " " Then
day_cell = " "

Else
'Do nothing
End If
Exit Sub

multiple_changes:
Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16

Do While A <= 42
i = 2
Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

If Cells(i, A) = "Green" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Green"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Green"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Red"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"

ElseIf Cells(i, A) = " " And Cells(i, B) = " " Then
Cells(i, c) = " "

Else
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

A = A + 4
B = A + 1
c = A + 2

Loop
End Sub
```

And this is in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call Module1.single_change(Target)

End Sub
```

Originally my codes had Runtime Error "Application Defined or Object-defined Error" but all `If` and `ElseIf` statements returned correct values. After changing my codes to the one a user recommended (see here [VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when using Range.Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970534/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-using)), cell value always change on its own accord even though I put a different value.

For example, when I entered `Rollup` in cell N2 (column Sales) then `Green` in cell O2 (column Production), cell P2 (column Day) was supposed to return `Green` per the `ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Green" Then day_cell = "Green"`. However, when I pressed Enter after filling cell O2 (Production), cell N2 (Sales) automatically changed to `Green`. Then after that, I changed cell N2 back to `Rollup` and the Macro worked.

[Print screen from result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5h6g.png)

Does anyone know what's going on? Thank you very much! Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Side note: maybe condense your question to a [reprex], specifically emphasis on the "minimal."

Comment: Plus people are more likely to help if you *indent* your code so the structure is easier to scan.  That will also make *your* life easier.

Comment: You code operates on the assumption that Target is a single cell - that may not always be the case, so you should either screen out multi-cell Target ranges so they don't trigger your code, or figure out how your code should handle them and make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to your problem.

I haven't looked at the returned results of your methods but I would suggest to refactor your code to make it more readable.

You might be able to spot the issue yourself.

Scrap all those `If..ElseIf...Else` statements and replace them with a `Select` which is much easier to read (and much faster).

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Green As String = "Green"
Private Const Rollup As String = "Rollup"
Private Const Yellow As String = "Yellow"

Sub Something()

    Dim A As Long, B As Long, C As Long, i As Long

    Select Case True
        Case Cells(i, A) = Green  And Cells(i, B) = Rollup: Cells(i, C) = Green
        Case Cells(i, A) = Rollup And Cells(i, B) = Rollup: Cells(i, C) = Rollup
        Case Cells(i, A) = Rollup And Cells(i, B) = Green:  Cells(i, C) = Green

        'Add more cases here...

    End Select

End Sub
```

Good luck.